# (Python) Unable to sum column based on condition ==0 from another column

Tags: python, sum, conditional-statements

I am working with a large database of deposit (~600,000 rows), and my task is to slot the deposit based on their tenor 'bucket' i.e. a 'bucket' would have lower and upper limits in days (e.g. 0-30 days, 31-60 days etc). The simplified raw data is as followed ('LCY_CURR_BALANCE' is value of deposit, 'RM' is tenor):

[image]

As the NaN in 'RM' column signify non-maturity deposits, I fill them with 0, then change the column type from float to integer, using this code line:

`MIS035A['KHCL']=MIS035A['KHCL'].fillna(0)#Replace NA with 0`

`MIS035A['KHCL']=MIS035A['KHCL'].astype(int)`

The result is as followed:

[image]

However, when I start to sum the 'LCY_CURR_BALANCE' column based on condition on 'RM', the following problem happens: if the condition ==0, the process would take **ridiculously** long to complete (abt 3 hours). Any other conditions would take less than 30 secs. The code I use for conditional summation is as followed:

`sumif_0=MIS035A[(MIS035A["KHCL"]==0)].sum()["ACY_CURR_BALANCE"]#condition ==0`
`sumif_1=MIS035A[(MIS035A["KHCL"]==1)].sum()["ACY_CURR_BALANCE"]#condition ==any other number`

I truly appreciate if someone can explain, or help me solve, why such issue happens. I suspects it may be because of my filling of NaN to 0. However I have not found any further explanation of the issue on the internet.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Did you try subseting your data into 1s and 0s and then performing the sum?

Comment: you have a big data, it is better to subset it (in my opinion)

Answer (score 1):

***How I would tackle the problem***

```
data_0 = MIS035A[MIS035A["KHCL"]==0]

data_1 = MIS035A[MIS035A["KHCL"]==1]

sum_0 = data_0["LCY_CURR_BALANCE"].sum()
sum_1 = data_1["LCY_CURR_BALANCE"].sum()
```

Since you have a huge data, it is better to subset it to run your calculations faster.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It does work much faster this way, although that means I have to split the ==0 condition from the rest (I planned to put all numerical conditions in an array and loop through the array). Nice solution btw!

Comment: I would consult someone with more knowledge than me when it comes to loops, I am not a computer scientist. Hopefully if you face another problem with speed, someone can help.